# Why my multiple canvas animation(requestAnimationFrame) is working only for one element?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I don't understand why requestAnimationFrame in my code work only for one element. I want animate both borders... my code in codepen -> http://codepen.io/zey_ser/pen/RPXovp

```
<div>
  <div id="valueForAnimation" style="display:none;">10</div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" 
   height="100"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="valueForAnimation2" style="display:none;">85</div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="100" 
   height="100"></canvas>
</div>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop animation</button>

animatedBorders('#myCanvas','valueForAnimation');
animatedBorders('#myCanvas2','valueForAnimation2');
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function animatedBorders (selector,selectorValue){  
canvas = document.querySelector(selector);
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
...
////////////////////
drawRect();
ID = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
drawText();
////////////////////
function drawRect(){
...
}
function drawLine(){
...
}
function drawText(){
...
}

function animationLoop(){
  drawLine();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use `var ctx` by omiting this you created a variable of window.ctx, the second time your function runs the first ctx is over written with the second, and that is why only the second one runs.

This is what the first 3 lines of animatedBorders function should look like:

```
function animatedBorders(selector, selectorValue) {
  canvas = document.querySelector(selector);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

with the only noticeable change, the addition of `var` before `ctx`